# Trabajar con parametros de una tabla mediante Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un archivo `.csv` que contiene este tipo de datos:

```
Nombre   Curso     Nota  
Miguel   Primero   8
Juan     Primer    2
Pedro    Segundo   6
Luisa    Primero   6
Teresa   Primero   3
Pepe     Segundo   5
Ana      Segundo   6
Natalia  Segundo   4
Maria    Primero   3
```

¿Como hago para por ejemplo sacar la media de la nota de los de primero?¿Y para sacar la cantidad total de los de segundo?

Para sacar la cantidad he probado algo así pero me da error, y para la media pienso que si se la cantidad total puedo dividirla con su sumatorio.

```
print len(archivo.Curso=='Segundo')
```

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 1):

No se como está tu codigo en este momento, pero los pasos que debes seguir son:

- Importar el archivo con Pandas: Así tendras un objeto de tipo Frame, que te dara facilidadades para indexado y filtrado
- Usar operadores de numpy para arreglos: Una vez filtrado la seccion de la tabla que requieres, puedes operar los valores con los operadores numpy.mean(), numpy.sum(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar vamos a reproducir tu ejemplo en un `dataframe` de pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """
Nombre   Curso     Nota  
Miguel   Primero   8
Juan     Primer    2
Pedro    Segundo   6
Luisa    Primero   6
Teresa   Primero   3
Pepe     Segundo   5
Ana      Segundo   6
Natalia  Segundo   4
Maria    Primero   3
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

Una posibilidad es agrupar y calcular las dos métricas: la media y la cantidad. Esto puede resolverse fácilmente usando [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby), con `.agg()` aplicamos las funciones de agregación, en nuestro caso `mean` y `count`, con `.reset_index()` hacemos que `Curso` sea una columna más y no un índice :

```
totales = df.groupby(['Curso'])['Nota'].agg(['mean', 'count']).reset_index()
print(totales)

     Curso  mean  count
0   Primer  2.00      1
1  Primero  5.00      4
2  Segundo  5.25      4
```

Para acceder luego a los valores individuales de cada celda, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
print("La media de Primero es   : {0}".format(totales.loc[totales['Curso'] == 'Primero', 'mean'].values[0]))
print("La cantidad de Segundo es: {0}".format(totales.loc[totales['Curso'] == 'Segundo', 'count'].values[0]))

La media de Primero es   : 5.0
La cantidad de Segundo es: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como ha dicho @gustavovelascoh, leyendo el csv con pandas te facilita hacer operaciones con sus columnas.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de qué puedes hacer con ello, pero lo mejor es echarle un ojo a la documentación de Pandas:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Además en ella encuentras un 'Cookbook' con ejemplos cortos muy útiles:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('notas.csv') #Aquí tienes la opción de indicar un sparador concreto de tus datos, ejem: df = pd.read_csv('notas.csv', sep=';')
notas = df['Nota'] #Extrar la columna 'Notas'
mean = notas.mean() #Hacer la media de las notas
num_segundo = len(df[df.Curso == 'Segundo']) #Ver el número de alumnos de segundo
```